# Wrong path in access vba msado reference

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I have an Access application that VBA references to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects` but I find that the path to the `msado28.tlb` type library is wrong (point to a network location!!!).

I found a PC that it does not have problem and the correct path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado28.tlb`.

I tried to point to this location but nothing happened!!

The pc's have Windows 7.

Comment: I thought to copy the msado28.tlb from the original location to that network path... but it seems not a permanent solution

Comment: Why at all using a file reference? Why don't you just use one of the `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library` entries of the list in the references dialog? This is the common way and all of them don't point to a file in the network.

Comment: I didn't describe anything different. What you said is what I said

Comment: As I have already said all references to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library points to msadoxx.tlb files in a network path but there are not such files in this location. Εven worse when i go from Browse to find the right file then I find it but nothing happens

Comment: Two options:
1. Re-installation of Win7
2. re-registration of ADO .tlb files

Comment: I need to avoid re-installation of win7 cause there are too many softwares already installed that we do not know how to restore them